# Error with Dell Datasafe

Tags: laptop

I have a Dell laptop. When I switch it on, it launches properly, but has a notification that tells *Dell datasafe local backup stop working*, with the options

1. to check online solution
2. to close the program.

I have tried several times to click for online solution as well as to close the program, but the notification persists. I couldn't mend or repair it. Therefore I prefer to get help online.

What is the possible solution?
 Does it have any problem if I uninstall it?
What could be the cause if I continue with outrepairing or trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Please say more about the local back up device, the place where backups go.

Answer (score 0):

If you were not using Dell Datasafe, you are safe to uninstall it. It is an obsolete online backup and file sharing program which is being terminated. If you are using it, Dell is supporting to the end of existing agreements.

> Dell™ DataSafe Online service will be shut down on June 11, 2015. Dell
>   will service your existing account to its full term. In anticipation
>   of account expiration, please take this opportunity to download your
>   data from your Dell™ DataSafe Online account onto your computer. Your
>   data will be permanently deleted from the Dell™ DataSafe Online system
>   no fewer than 30 days after your account expiration.

[Source](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/services/datasafe/map?c=us&l=en&cs=19)